# Drupal Module For Requesting/Processing Product License Key

Tags: drupal

I want to place a form on my drupal site that will allow users to request a product license key.  So its just a form where several fields are filled out and back would come the license key.  How would I go about implementing something like this in drupal.  Users is already registered with the site when this request is made. I would like to know how to just save off the form and generate a response with the keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a combination of webform and rules.